# Oracle self join to retrieve data

Tags: oracle, plsql

**EmployeeA**:

```
E_no  E_name   E_Ag_ref  E_Type  Status          E_Entry_Date
----------------------------------------------------------------    
1B    Mike     12345       B     Continued   08/01/2013 12:24:20
1S   steve     12345       S     Continued   08/01/2013 12:25:20
2B   Radek     1001        B     Continued   08/01/2013 16:24:20
2S   Rafal     1001        S     nContinued  06/01/2014 20:24:20
```

**Query:**

```
select * 
from 
    Employee E1,
    Employee E2 
where 
    ((substr(E1.E_no,1,length(E1.E_no)-1) || 'S')=E2.E_no and E2.E_Type='S' )
    and ( ( TO_CHAR(E1.E_Entry_Date,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') )  between ((:startDate)||' '|| (:startTime)) and  ((:endDate)||' '||(:endTime)) OR ('ALL'  between (:startTime) and (:endTime))  )
    and ( ( TO_CHAR(E2.E_Entry_Date,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') )  between ((:startDate)||' '|| (:startTime)) and  ((:endDate)||' '||(:endTime)) OR ('ALL'  between (:startTime) and (:endTime))  )
    and E2.E_Type='B' and E1.status='Continued' and E2.status='Continued'
```

Above query returns below 3 records.

```
1B    Mike     12345       B     Continued   08/01/2013 12:24:20
1S   steve     12345       S     Continued   08/01/2013 12:25:20
2B   Radek     1001        B     Continued   08/01/2013 16:24:20
```

**Input parameters:**

```
startDate:06/01/2012
endDate:  08/01/2013

startTime: 13:00:00
endTIme:   21:00:00
```

**Expected Result:**

```
1B    Mike     12345       B     Continued   08/01/2013 12:24:20
```

Please can any one suggest ,how to fix this.

Regards,
Komaturi

Comment: So what is the logic supposed to be? Also, convert the date/time parameters to a date and compare with the date you are storing, rather than converting the stored date to a string to compare to the inputs

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Answer (score 0):

i think you're trying to do this:

```
SQL> select e1.*
  2    from employee e1
  3         inner join employee e2
  4                 on substr(e1.e_no, 1, length(e1.e_no)-1) || 'S' = e2.e_no
  5   where e1.E_Type = 'B'
  6     and e2.E_Type = 'S'
  7     and e1.status='Continued'
  8     and e2.status='Continued'
  9     and (  '' = 'ALL' -- set the left side to ALL if you don't want to compare dates.
 10          or (e1.E_Entry_Date between to_date('06/01/2012 13:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
 11                                  and to_date('08/01/2013 21:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
 12              and e2.E_Entry_Date between to_date('06/01/2012 13:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
 13                                      and to_date('08/01/2013 21:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
 14         );

E_ E_NAME       E_AG_REF E STATUS     E_ENTRY_DATE
-- ---------- ---------- - ---------- -------------------
1B Mike            12345 B Continued  08/01/2013 12:24:20
```

your original SQL cannot be what you actually run. as even if we gloss over the date to char conversion stuff, you had

```
    E2.E_Type='S'
AND E2.E_Type='B'
```

which cant be true (these weren't OR'd at all). you probably meant `E1.e_type = 'B'` I guess.